# How to deploy the django app in AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'am new to django.Can you please provide the complete deployment in elastic beanstalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need require some credentials,

AWS Elastic Beanstalk needs the following information to deploy an application:

```
AWS access key ID

AWS secret key

Service region

Application name

Environment name

Solution stack
```

Here is the complete reference [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html)

Comment: Thanks dhana. I followed your link. I find the sollution . Thank u very much...

Comment: Good luck @Gowri. If it is useful please accept it. Because more users  find the right solution.